# My validation doesn't work in one project but works in another

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I connected validation to my project, but it just does not work. I checked several times whether I forgot anything - everything seems to be fine. I created test files: Controller, service, repository, Entity, mapper, dto and tested it on this project (it still didn’t work), and on another one, where validation works, and everything has already started on it.

Entity:

```
package com.example.entity;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "test")
public class TestEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "test")
    private String test;
}
```

TestResponse:

```
package com.example.dto.response;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Data
public class TestResponse {
    private Long id;
    @NotNull
    private String test;
}
```

TestRequest:

```
package com.example.dto.request;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


@Data
public class TestRequest {
    @NotNull
    private String test;
}
```

Repo, controller and service:

```
package com.example.repository;

import com.example.entity.TestEntity;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TestRepo extends CrudRepository<TestEntity, Long> {
}







package com.example.controller;

import com.example.dto.request.TestRequest;
import com.example.dto.response.TestResponse;
import com.example.mapper.TestMapperImpl;
import com.example.service.TestService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import javax.validation.Valid;

@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {
    private TestService testService;
    private TestMapperImpl testMapper;

    @PostMapping("/add")
    public ResponseEntity<TestResponse>add(@Valid @RequestBody TestRequest testRequest){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(testMapper.toDto(testService.add(testMapper.fromDto(testRequest))), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}












package com.example.service;

import com.example.entity.TestEntity;
import com.example.repository.TestRepo;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestService {
    private TestRepo testRepo;
    public TestEntity add(TestEntity entity){
       return testRepo.save(entity);
    }
}
```

Postman Screen.
It should throw an error but it doesn't

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xim8o.png)

Its my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>kursova</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.5.3.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
        <org.lombok.version>1.18.26</org.lombok.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.33</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <version>${org.lombok.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--Mapper-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- This is needed when using Lombok 1.18.16 and above -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- Mapstruct should follow the lombok path(s) -->
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <!-- Set the componentModel to 'spring' by default -->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <compilerArg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </compilerArg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `@Basic` annotation has an attribute called `optional` which is a boolean parameter that defines whether the marked field or property allows null. It defaults to true.

Refer to [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-basic-annotation#why-use) that explains when you should be using it.

Try and apply the `@NotNull` annotation directly to your entity.